# Rails js.erb response not sending locals to Haml partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I realize this is similar to some other questions, but I have been through a fair number of those and I think I'm doing what they suggested, but my code is still not working.

So, as the title says, I'm attempting to load a partial from a js.erb file (in response to an AJAX call.) However, it is not working correctly.

full_list.html.haml:

```
=link_to(test_path(@work), id: "privacy-button", remote: true) do
    = render "privacy_button_content", locals: {:show_others => @work.show_others}
```

_privacy_button_content.html.haml:

```
-if locals[:show_others] == false
    -test_string = "twas false"
-else
    -test_string = "twas true"
%p = test_string
```

works_controller.rb:

```
 def test_function 
   @work.model_function
   respond_with(:layout => false)
 end
```

test_function.js.erb:

```
$("#privacy-button").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'privacy_button_content', locals: {:show_others => @work.show_others}) %>");
```

So the full_list has privacy_button, which is rendering the partial, and the response to clicking the #privacy-button should be to modify something in the controller, and get the response.js.erb.

This works correctly on page load (so passing the local to the partial does work,) but whenever I run the AJAX call I'm getting

```
(undefined local variable or method `locals' for #<#<Class:0x00000005006338>:0x000000068481f8>):
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've figured it out. It seems that specific error I was getting had to do with the render syntax when working when haml (I got the same issue when I specified `render :partial` from the view, so it wasn't unique to the js.erb.)

The code in partial.js.erb now looks like:

```
$("#privacy-button").html("<%= escape_javascript render("privacy_button_content", :locals => {:show_others => @work.show_others}) %>");
```

As you can see, the main difference is having `render "works_group_list"` rather than `render( partial: => "works_group_list"`. As I said, I believe this may be related to my views being written in Haml, though it should be noted that the render(partial:...) syntax does work when not attempting to pass local variables from a js.erb.

I was also getting some little issues because I kept referring to something as #my_element in the js when in the html it was #my-element. So if you're encountering this issue, checking your spelling (for the thirtieth time) never hurts.

Edit:

Just a note, as others have pointed out using the locals hash is not mandatory. So the line of code could instead be

```
$("#privacy-button").html("<%= escape_javascript render("privacy_button_content", :show_others => @work.show_others ) %>");
```

This will work as long as you update your partial appropriately (referring to `var` instead of `locals[:var]`).

Answer (score 1):

Update `_privacy_button_content.html.haml` as below:

```
-if show_others == false  
    -test_string = "twas false"
-else
    -test_string = "twas true"
%p = test_string
```

When you pass `show_others` in locals hash, a local variable would be created for you named `show_others`. You can access it as `show_others` in the partial and not `locals[:show_others]`.

Refer to **[Passing local variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables)** in Rails Guides.

Comment: Hey Kirti, thanks for getting back to me. I just gave that a shot, and unfortunately it didn't work (whereas before it loaded the partial on the initial page load but not from the javascript, with this change it does not load on page load.) I know I could be passing them as just "show_others" => @work.show_others, which would make the syntax you suggested for the partial work, but I switched over to the locals hash because I saw a few people saying it might help with my issue (it didn't though.) think that my issue may be related to moving between haml and erb, so I'm working on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Kirti Thorat's change and then change

```
= render "privacy_button_content", locals: {:show_others => @work.show_others}
```

for

```
= render "privacy_button_content", show_others: @work.show_others
```

Also remember that views should not have logic, it should be in a **helper** or in a **decorator**

BTW: I think `%p = test_string` should be `%p= test_string`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. As I mentioned to Kirti, I'm aware that this syntax is possible and how to use it from both ends, but passing it this way vs with the locals hash was not making a difference with my problem (I was actually doing this first.) I will, however, edit my response  to mention that this syntax is also possible, and probably superior.